# Why do I get different results of goodness of fit test using AD tests from different R libraries?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, anderson-darling-test

I am trying to find the best method for goodness of fit while testing my data with different models of distributions. I need to use AD test. So I have compared results using two different `R` libraries:

```
library(nortest)
library(goftest)

x <- rnorm(1000, mean=0, sd=1)
nortest::ad.test(x)
goftest::ad.test(x,"pnorm", mean=0, sd=1)
```

The results are as follows:

```
> nortest::ad.test(x)

        Anderson-Darling normality test

data:  x
A = 0.21402, p-value = 0.8506

> goftest::ad.test(x,"pnorm", mean=0, sd=1)

        Anderson-Darling test of goodness-of-fit
        Null hypothesis: Normal distribution
        with parameters mean = 0, sd = 1

data:  x
An = 0.92928, p-value = 0.3966
```

My question is why `A` (`An`)  and `p-value` results have different values in each case? I understand that in the second case I test with assumption of some parameteres, but I do not understand difference between both testing procedures.

My question is mainly because I need a procedure that works like `nortest::ad.test` (without parameters) but also lets you to test hypothesis about distribution models other than normal. Procedures from the `goftest` library require parameters or assume defaults (`mean = 0`, `sd = 1)`.

Or is there another `R` library which does the same like `nortest` but also for other distribution models?

Comment: **I would read the documentation:** [`nortest::ad.test`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nortest/nortest.pdf) explicitly standardizes the data, thereby testing whether the data come from *some* normal distribution, whereas [`goftest::ad.test`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/goftest/goftest.pdf) does not standardize.  A quick simulation will verify this, such as `nortest::ad.test(x <- rnorm(10,10))` and `goftest::ad.test(x)`

Comment: @whuber: Thank you, now it is clear for me. I have also found an information that both libraries use the same procedure but `nortest` adjusts `An` and `p-value`for the effect of estimating the parameters. So I can now redefine my question: is there a formula that I can use to adjust results from `goftest` to gain the same result as from `nortest`?